# How to download tarball from Github

Tags: tar, curl, github

I have this:

```
curl -L "https://github.com/cmtr/cp-go-api/tarball/$commit_id" | tar x -C "$project_dir/"
```

I am just trying to download a tarball from github and extract it to an existing directory. The problem is I am getting this error:

```
Step 10/13 : RUN curl -L "https://github.com/channelmeter/cp-go-api/tarball/$commit_id" | tar x -C "$project_dir/"
 ---> Running in a883449de956
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     35      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    35
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -L "https://github.com/channelmeter/cp-go-api/tarball/$commit_id" | tar x -C "$project_dir/"' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

does anyone know why it's not a tar archive? If you go to github.com in the browser and put in this pattern, it will download a tar.gz archive:

```
https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/tarball/<sha>
```

so not sure why it's not working.

Comment: What do you get if you got to this page (outside of a pipeline)? I can't find the project. Is it private?

Comment: https://github.com/cmtr/cp-go-api/tarball doesn't work for me.

Comment: the repo is private, the actual org name is not cmtr

Comment: it's possible that curl can't download it without credentials, so that's probably what is wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So ultimately it's because Github wants credentials. Without 2-factor auth, you can just do this with curl:

```
curl -u username:password https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/tarball/<sha>
```

but if you have 2-factor auth setup, then you need to use a Github access token, and you should use api.github.com instead of github.com, like so:

```
 curl -L "https://api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/tarball/$commit_sha?access_token=$github_token" | tar -xz -C "$extract_dir/"
```

the access token thing is documented here:
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line

Comment: query param `access_token=$github_token` is deprecated, looks like the suggestion is to use a header like `curl -H "Authorization: token $github_token" ...`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to this is to use a GitHub cookie. It still starts with the
normal user/pass, but after the initial request, you can make further requests
by utilizing the cookie. Here is example with PHP:

```php
<?php

# GET
$get = curl_init('https://github.com/login');
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'github.txt');
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$log = curl_exec($get);
curl_close($get);

# POST
preg_match('/name="authenticity_token" value="([^"]*)"/', $log, $auth);
$pf['authenticity_token'] = $auth[1];
$pf['login'] = getenv('USER');
$pf['password'] = getenv('PASS');
$post = curl_init('https://github.com/session');
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'github.txt');
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pf);
curl_exec($post);
```

Then after that, you can use shell cURL with `-b github.txt`, or PHP cURL with
`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE github.txt`. Make sure to `curl_close` as shown above, else
the cookie file gets created after its needed.